# Apache POI rate formula not working if data is big

Tags: function, apache-poi, rate

Rate Formula is not working as expected for big values...

1. RATE(85.77534246575343, -1589.0, -18664.0, 5855586.0)  in physical file it returns 0.05819488005
2. if the same formula we tried to set through POI   returns 0.009056339275922086..

   3. Even we tried to save the excel and open same 0.009056339275922086 is returned..

Code used to set in POI :

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
XSSFRow  row = sheet.createRow(1);
XSSFCell  cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
cell.setCellFormula("RATE(85.77534246575343, -1589.0, -18664.0, 5855586.0)");
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell);
cell.getNumericCellValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Rate](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/functions/Rate.java?view=markup) function of `apache poi` states that it "// find root by Newton secant method". That's nonsense since [Secant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) is only a Quasi-Newton method. And "[If the initial values are not close enough to the root, then there is no guarantee that the secant method converges.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method#Convergence)".

So the default `guess` of `0.1` seems not "close enough" and so if we are using `cell.setCellFormula("RATE(85.77534246575343, -1589.0, -18664.0, 5855586.0, 0, 0.06)");` - note the explicit setting of `type` and `guess` properties and having the  `guess` property "close enough" to the result of `0.05819488005`- then the formula evaluates properly.

If `apache poi` really would use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method), then the function would evaluate properly also using the default `guess` of `0.1`. The disadvantage of Newton's method is that it requires the evaluation of both `f` and its derivative `f′` at every step. So it may be slower than the Secant method in some cases.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

public class ExcelRATEFunction {

 private static double calculateRateNewton(double nper, double pmt, double pv, double fv, double type, double guess) {

  int FINANCIAL_MAX_ITERATIONS = 20;
  double FINANCIAL_PRECISION = 0.0000001;

  double y, y1, xN = 0, f = 0, i = 0;

  double rate = guess;

  //find root by Newtons method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), not secant method!
  //Formula see: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_Derivation_of_Financial_Formulas#PV.2C_FV.2C_PMT.2C_NPER.2C_RATE

  f = Math.pow(1 + rate, nper);
  y = pv * f + pmt * ((f - 1) / rate) * (1 + rate * type) + fv;

  //first derivative:
  //y1 = (pmt * nper * type * Math.pow(rate,2) * f - pmt * f - pmt * rate * f + pmt * nper * rate * f + pmt * rate + pmt + nper * pv * Math.pow(rate,2) * f) / (Math.pow(rate,2) * (rate+1));
  y1 = (f * ((pmt * nper * type + nper * pv) * Math.pow(rate,2) + (pmt * nper - pmt) * rate - pmt) + pmt * rate + pmt) / (Math.pow(rate,3) + Math.pow(rate,2));

  xN = rate - y/y1;

  while ((Math.abs(rate - xN) > FINANCIAL_PRECISION) && (i < FINANCIAL_MAX_ITERATIONS)) {

   rate = xN;

   f = Math.pow(1 + rate, nper);
   y = pv * f + pmt * ((f - 1) / rate) * (1 + rate * type) + fv;

   //first derivative:
   //y1 = (pmt * nper * type * Math.pow(rate,2) * f - pmt * f - pmt * rate * f + pmt * nper * rate * f + pmt * rate + pmt + nper * pv * Math.pow(rate,2) * f) / (Math.pow(rate,2) * (rate+1));
   y1 = (f * ((pmt * nper * type + nper * pv) * Math.pow(rate,2) + (pmt * nper - pmt) * rate - pmt) + pmt * rate + pmt) / (Math.pow(rate,3) + Math.pow(rate,2));

   xN = rate - y/y1;
   ++i;

   System.out.println(rate+", "+xN+", "+y+", "+y1);
  }

  rate = xN;    
  return rate;

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Row  row = sheet.createRow(1);
  Cell  cell = row.createCell(1);

  cell.setCellFormula("RATE(85.77534246575343, -1589.0, -18664.0, 5855586.0, 0, 0.06)");
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
  CellType celltype = evaluator.evaluateFormulaCellEnum(cell);

  double value = 0.0;
  if (celltype == CellType.NUMERIC) {
   value = cell.getNumericCellValue();
   System.out.println(value);
  }

  workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);

  value = calculateRateNewton(85.77534246575343, -1589.0, -18664.0, 5855586.0, 0, 0.1);
  System.out.println(value);

  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelRATEFunction.xlsx"));
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```